# Symfony2 Dependency Injection load configs based on a condition

Tags: symfony, configuration, dependency-injection

I want to load configuration parameters based on a condition in symfony2.

If given "driver" parameter is "a" then require and load this parameters, else, require and load another parameters.

In dependency injection configuration, i must set some rules to all parameters like can not be null etc.

How can i do this?